# How does this function to create a PowerSet in Python works?

Tags: python

I was looking for a way to create power-sets(all possible sub-sets of a set) in Python without using modules.

I've found lots a ways to do it online. There are many answers in this forum alone. But, although all the codes work properly, I could not find a answer that I was able to understand what the code was doing. I'm new to Python and my main goal is learning and not finding a code that just works.

Can someone explain to me how the following code produce the list of subsets?

```
def powerset(s):
    x = len(s)
    for i in range(1 << x):
        print [s[j] for j in range(x) if (i & (1 << j))]

powerset([4,5,6])
```

Output

```
[]
[4]
[5]
[4, 5]
[6]
[4, 6]
[5, 6]
[4, 5, 6]
```

The things I really did not understand and could not find are:

```
range(1 << x)
if (i & (1 << j))
```

But in general I have no ideia of what this code is doing.

Comment: These are Python bitwise operations.  `1 << x` number 1 bitshift left by x (equivalent to 2**x).  `a & b` is bitwise and of numbers a, b.

Comment: Code is using the binary count method to generate a power set [reference](https://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/power-set.html). 
Similar code to [above](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/power-set/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a side note, power set of X is commonly denoted as 2^X in mathematical literature. If there are N elements in set X, the size of a power set is 2^N.

One way to generate power set is by bitmap: Imagine you have N elements layed out as a size N array, and you enumerate all integers from 0 to 2^N-1 and write them in their binary form, then each element of the power set is the subset picked from the array according to each binary number.

For example, if you have `[4, 5, 6]` and you enumerate 0 to 7=2^3-1, you have these numbers and the corresponding subsets:

```
0 = 000 -> []
1 = 001 -> [6]
2 = 010 -> [5]
3 = 011 -> [5, 6]
...
6 = 110 -> [4, 5]
7 = 111 -> [4, 5, 6]
```

To convert this into code, you notice the following:

- 2^N equals to `1 << N`, i.e. shift the binary representation of 1 by N bits to the left
- If you have a binary number `x`, to check if position `j` from the right is 1, you do `x & (1 << j)`; which `1 << j` is to shift 1 by j bits and `&` is binary AND operation, so the result of the AND is 0 if and only if bit j of `x` is not 1

Therefore you have your code.